# sumar o dividir y que el resultado sea con dos decimales pero sin redondear javacript

Tags: php, javascript, html

este es mi código y me limita a dos decimales pero el problema es que redondea , como hago para que no me redondee el valor si por ejemplo el resultado es 14.899995
que el resultado sea  14.89 y no que me redondee:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Untitled</title>
       <script src="../public/js/jquery_min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
      </script>
    </head>
    <body>

     <form name="form1" method="post"  action=""> 
            <p> 
                Primer sumando: <input  id="precio_venta" name="precio_venta"   type="text" size="8" maxlength="100">  
            </p> 
            <p> 

              <div class="col-sm-3">
                <div class="form-group label-floating">
                    <label class="control-label">IVA</label>
                        <select id="porcentaje" name="porcentaje" class="form-control selectpicker">
                            <option disabled="" selected="">Seleccione ...</option>
                            <option value="1.05">5%</option>
                            <option value="1.19">19%</option>
                        </select>                                                   
                </div>
            </div>
            </p> 

            Original number: <input name="original" type="text"  />
            <br />"Rounded" number: <input name="rounded" type="text" placeholder="readonly" readonly>
            <p>Resultado es: <input id="resultado" type="text" size="10" maxlength="10"> 
                <button class="btn btn-warning" type="button" style="color:#FFFFFF;" onclick="porcentaje_iva();"><i class="fa fa-dollar fa-1x fa-lg" style="color:#FFFFFF;"></i> Calcular IVA</button>
            </p> 
        </form>
    </body>
</html>

<script>
            function porcentaje_iva()
            {  
                var porcentaje = document.getElementById("porcentaje");
                if(porcentaje.value == "1.19" || porcentaje.value == "1.05" ){
                    var n1 = parseFloat(document.form1.precio_venta.value);
                    var n2 = parseFloat(document.form1.porcentaje.value);
                    $(function() {
                        $('#precio_venta').number(true, 2);
                        document.form1.precio_venta.value=(n1 / n2);
                    });
                }
            }
</script>
```

Comment: Te doy la bienvenida a SO. Hay algo que se llama *identar*  cuando se escribe código. Aplicarlo ayuda a entender cómo está organizado el programa, a revisarlo, a encontrar errores. El código que compartiste estaba horriblemente organizado e imposible de revisar: espacios enorrrrmes a la izquirda, saltos de líneas exagerados sin ningún sentido, etc. Yo me he permitido mejorar eso en tu pregunta para poder ahora revisar cuál es el problema del que hablas. Aunque hay más malas prácticas en tu código: no respetas en el HTML la prioridad de contenedores y en JS tampoco la prioridad de funciones.

Comment: Puedes intentar algo como esto: `var num=Math.floor(valorSuma * 100) / 100;
console.log(num);`

Comment: siempre puedes hacer un substring o hacer un toFix del resultado y así no redondeas

Answer (score 0):

Puedes intentar con `Number.toPrecision()`, aqui te dejo un poco de documentacion sobre eso [Number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toPrecision)

```js
let n1 = 40.5, n2 = 20;
result = n1/n2

console.log(Number(result).toPrecision(3))
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerlo asi:

```
var num=14.899995;
num.toFixed(2);
```

Answer (score 0):

muchas gracias, ya consegui que solo me muestre los dos primeros decimales sin redondedar.

hola, tengo un ejemplo que te puede servir , te muestra el resultado sin redondear simplemente muestra el resultado y los dos primeros decimales:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Untitled</title>
   <script src="../public/js/jquery_min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>





    <form name="form1" method="post"  action=""> 
        <p> 
            Primer sumando: <input  id="precio_venta" name="precio_venta"   type="text" size="8" maxlength="100">  
        </p> 
        <p> 

          <div class="col-sm-3">
                                         <div class="form-group label-floating">
                                                <label class="control-label">IVA</label>
                                                <select id="porcentaje" name="porcentaje" class="form-control selectpicker">
                                                    <option disabled="" selected="">Seleccione ...</option>
                                                    <option value="1.05">5%</option>
                                                    <option value="1.19">19%</option>



                                                </select>


                                            </div>
                                            </div>



        </p> 




        Original number: <input name="original" type="text"  />  



        <p>
            Resultado es: <input id="resultado" type="text" size="10" maxlength="10"> 

                <button class="btn btn-warning" type="button" style="color:#FFFFFF;" onclick="porcentaje_iva();"><i class="fa fa-dollar fa-1x fa-lg" style="color:#FFFFFF;"></i> Calcular IVA</button>

        </p> 
    </form>
</body>
</html>
 <script>
        function porcentaje_iva()
        {  



            if(porcentaje.value == "1.19" || porcentaje.value == "1.05" ){

            var n1 = Math.floor(precio_venta.value * 100) / 100;

           var n2 = Math.floor(porcentaje.value * 100) / 100;

           $(function() {

       document.form1.precio_venta.value=(n1 / n2);

         var n = Math.floor(precio_venta.value * 100) / 100;


         var x= precio_venta.value=(n1 / n2);

         document.form1.precio_venta.value= n.toFixed(2);

    });

            }


}


    </script>
```